# How to align angular material datatable header of the column content vertically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material datatable, i want to align the contents of the header of a column vertically. I used br or p tag but it didn't work. The contents of the header of the column are still aligned horizontally.
Here is the code of the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), set all the contents inside a parent. and on that parent set `display: flex; flex-direction: column`

```
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matSort >
  <div class="flex-container">
      <span>Name</span>
      <input *ngIf="true" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectInput" >
      <select *ngIf="true" [(ngModel)]="selectValue" class="form-control">
        <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of options">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</th>
```

```
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lf12zu?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)